# Do I need to prime concrete floor after scarifying but before crack isolation membrane?

Tags: concrete, tile, preparation

I have about 2000sqft of stained concrete slab that I want to put tile over. There are a few small cracks, all less than 1/8th inch but the tile I want to lay is 6x36 so I think I should put down a crack isolation membrane before tile.

Is there a step between grinding off the stain (this is called scarifying right?) and rolling on the crack isolation membrane. I was looking at products similar to mapei's mapelastic CI if that helps.

Comment: I use a dye in concrete to color it and no matter what you do you can not get rid of that coloring. I might acid etch to make sure it was clean but that would be how I prepped for tile.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should leave my original comment but the installation instructions I just found for the crack isolation membrane specifically mention not using an acid etch or stripper.  Sorry- I could've found this information before asking this question and leading you astray Ed Beal.

Comment: I have done hundreds of tile jobs they were my real speciality when I did not have enough work before becoming an electrician. I did all the tile on every flip and those were to cover cracks and improved visual not sure what brand you are using but a surface grind may leave stains that won’t bond without etching.

Answer (score 0):

If the color is just a surface coating the acid etch may be an acid coloring so just etching with muriatic acid and water mixture will both clean and rough up the surface so your membrane will stick.
After the appropriate rinse and wait to dry have at it and you should be good to continue.  A thin coloring may be an acid product. I etch old concrete 100% and rinse have been doing this many moons with great results , Rinse , squeegee, rinse squeegee rinse squeegee, a fan over the slam will dry it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a membrane like Kerdi for decoupling? For this you do need the mortar that holds the membrane to stick to the concrete, which likely means a primer after removing the old color overcoat. If the concrete was stained originally in its pouring, rather than having had an overcoat put on after it was dry, you can prime directly on the concrete after cleaning.

[image]